# Making a time series data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of time series observations like below

```
 Year/Month APR MAY JUN.......MAR
    2012     201 203 208...   2016
    2013     220 221 222......2018
    2014      ....................
     .        .
     .        .
     .        .
    2019      230 235 237      240
```

I need the data to be like this

```
 Period      Value
Apr-2012      .
May-2012      .  
Jun-2012      .
.
.
.
.
.
Apr-2013
May-2013
Jun-2013
.
.
.
Jan-2019
Feb-2019
Mar-2019       .
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you include the content of your real data frame. You can paste the output from `dput(mydata)`, where `mydata` is the data frame name.

Comment: you can also paste  `dput(head(mydata))` on your question  just to have an example of your dataset

Comment: i cant do that as it is showing the characters is longer than what can be pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `gather` the data into 'long' format and `unite` the 'Year/Month' column with 'key' to create the 'Period'

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
gather(df1, key, val, -`Year/Month`) %>% 
     unite(Period, key, `Year/Month`, sep="-") %>% 
     mutate(Period = as.yearmon(Period, '%b-%Y')) %>%
     arrange(Period)
#    Period val
#1 Apr 2012 201
#2 May 2012 203
#3 Jun 2012 208
#4 Apr 2013 220
#5 May 2013 221
#6 Jun 2013 222
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Year/Month` = 2012:2013, APR = c(201L, 220L), 
    MAY = c(203L, 221L), JUN = c(208L, 222L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. But it works in a different way. That is all the april months are  together for different years. But i want it to be all months for one year pasted below all month for other years and so on

Comment: With you data, it works pretty fine. But can we read a data insted of providing the data by typing?

Comment: @Nithin.M  You can directly read the data with `read.csv/read.table` etc `df1 <- read.csv("yourdata.csv")`  Here I assumed that you already read the data

Comment: Great. It works but still the output, with reference to you data is APR-2012 201 APR-2013 220 etc. What i want is APR-2012 201 MAY 2012 203 APR-2013 220 MAY-2013 221

Comment: @Nithin.M Where is the June data.  I don't find any difference except that you didn't show the June data which is showed in your expected

Comment: Sorry, June is also there. My point is all the months of one year should be followed by all the months of the next year. APR-2012, May-2012, Jun-2013 then Apr-2013, May-2013, Jun-2013. Here the output is APR-2012 APR-2013 MAY-2012 MAY-2013 JUN-2012 JUN-2013.

Comment: @Nithin.M  I am not getting that.  If you check the output, it is showing `Apr 2012`, `May 2012` etc. and the `arrange` is exactly doing the ordering

Comment: structure(list(Period = c("APR-2012", "APR-2013", "MAY-2012", 
"MAY-2013", "JUN-2012", "JUN-2013"), val = c(201L, 220L, 203L, 
221L, 208L, 222L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: This is how the output looks

Comment: @Nithin.M  Sorry, based on the example you showed, i don't get that

Comment: @akrun- actually it solved my problem. I didnt notice the arrange.. Thanks a lot for your time and patience

Comment: it would be more helfpul if i can sen you the data by mail

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
row.names(df) = df[,1]
with(data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(df[,-1]))),
         data.frame('Year-Month' = paste(Var1,Var2,sep='-'),Value=Freq))
```

or you can also do:

```
with(cbind(year=df[,1],stack(df[,-1])),
      data.frame(year=paste(year,ind,sep='-'),val=values)[order(year),])
```

Comment: With First command, there are two problems. First instead of Years, it is A,B,C etc. Secondly, again all the months are together and not the years. I want all the months of a year together.

Comment: @Nithin.M probably because your first column is not the `year/month` column.  when I wrote `df[,1]` this means the year-month column. So replace that with the appropriate column. Also the last issue is just a matter of ordering. You just need to order the data. Thats all

Comment: Yeah-Thank you for the time